# Need to have buttons on InfoPath form in a Site Page to direct to a specific URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, infopath, script, sitepages

I have an InfoPath Designer form that I created and placed into a Site Page. Now I would like each of the buttons on this form to be able to direct to specified URL. I've tried adding the script below to a Script Editor webpart, but it's not working:

```
<script>     
document.getElementById("CTRL15_5").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
window.location='http://www.google.com';
});
</script>
```

Is there another way to do this? Or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement. It is possible to create buttons that will open new pages. However, it is CRAZY difficult to do.

I will propose an alternative solution that we ended up doing.

I uploaded images that LOOK like buttons. The images of buttons themselves have links embedded which you can easily do in infopath designer. This solved the requirement.

So basically, in infopath designer, place the button images where you want. Embed hyperlinks on the images, and publish the form.

Let me know if that helps.

UPDATE...

Here is how you do it...

Step 1. Open the desired form in infopath designer.

Step 2. Navigate to the section where you wish to place the buttons.

Step 3. Using the top ribbon, click on the Insert tab, and click on Picture

Step 4. With the picture uploaded, click on the image.

Step 5. In the Insert Tab, click Hyperlink (important that the image is selected)

Step 6. Enter the desired URL.

Step 7. Save and publish the form.

See the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you add the links to them?

Comment: I will update my response.

Comment: See my updated message.

Comment: Okay, so that's all dandy, but I need it to display a value on top of it. When I get the form to enter a hyperlink, there are options to Display Text, but are grayed out. How can I enable this?

Comment: When you say a value, do you mean text over the images? Like a text to describe the button (image) the user will click on? In my case, we had 6 buttons, so I just created six images of buttons with the specific text on them. So the image was the button including the text.

Comment: No, it need it to display a dynamic value (integer) from a SharePoint List. I have it working in a Text Field, but I can't do it on this picture. For some reason it's disabled. I can only add the Link To options, not the Display...

Comment: I am afraid you won't likely be able to do that. The best you can do is have the text just next to the image. Like if you were making a table of these, you can have 1 column of your dynamic values, and the column to the right be image buttons that take you to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Edit buttons in InfoPath designer for this form.

**You can use [C# code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/infopath/form-templates/walkthrough-creating-a-basic-form-template-with-code)** in InfoPath, here is example with action on button..

You can also dynamically set field Value (like some link). [More info HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/infopath-form/aa942970(v=office.15)):

```
public void FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e)
{
   // Create XPathNavigator positioned at the root of the main data 
   // source.
   XPathNavigator myNav = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator()

   // Select employee field and set value to username.
   myNav.SelectSingleNode("//my:employee",this.NamespaceManager).
      SetValue(System.Environment.UserName);
}
```

[Another Examples here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/03/18/introduction-to-programming-in-infopath-2010/)

**or just edit in the Designer values if they are static.**

[Install VSTA for InfoPath manual.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-infopath-programming-environments-44b14193-b228-4a0a-aa5e-d05c48ff632a)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "edit buttons"?

Comment: added instructions

Comment: When trying to add code to my button, it says it requires VSTA, which I am not able to add to my work laptop. Is there any other options or ways around this until I can get that enabled?

Comment: why you cant install VSTA to your laptop?

Comment: An admin needs to install or configure settings on employee laptops, which could take who-knows how long...

Comment: but its prerequisite, so visit your IT technicians for install it, this is for 10 minutes.